# Multiple, Simultaneous Oauth in a Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, omniauth

My end goal is for users to have multiple 3rd party authentications at the same time.

Right now, I am using Devise to create users. Users can sign up via email or facebook or google and it works.  But now, after they have already signed up, I need them to also verify with, say, youtube or soundcloud.  So the user was created with devise, but I also need them to verify with other things.

Since Devise hogs omniauth for it's own purposes, I can't use omniauth on the side.

As I see it I have three options:

- Try to monkeypatch devise and get it to allow multiple authentications at the same time on one user
- Do oauth by hand on the side adjacent to current Devise implementation
- Scrap Devise and do something different

I would greatly appreciate any advice or other options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you need: http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/

They open sourced their code too!

Provider: https://github.com/joshsoftware/sso-devise-omniauth-provider
Client: https://github.com/joshsoftware/sso-devise-omniauth-client

Or even better, check out this: http://communityguides.heroku.com/articles/16

Answer (score 1):

> Try to monkeypatch devise and get it to allow multiple authentications at the same time on one use

You don't need to monkeypatch devise --- you can have your own oauth controller the has

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    # handle if already a twitter user
    # handle if a new user
    # use the `sign_in user` to sign_in the user
  end

  def twitter
    # handle if already a facebook user
    # handle if a new user
  end
end
```

and use it in routes

```
devise_for :user, 
         :controllers => {
           :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"
         }
```